# Camel: getting current route's exchange without specfying exchange as parameter

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, apache-camel

When I work with Camel almost every method I write has Exchange as a parameter, in order to get the current exchange by automatic binding.

Something like that:

```
class MyClass
{
    void doSomething(Exchange exchange, ........)
    {
        exchange.getIn().....

        .......
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the current exchange without specifying it as a parameter?

Maybe something like this....?

```
class MyClass
{
    @ExchangeAware
    Exchange exchange;

    void doSomething(........)
    {
        exchange.getIn().....

        .......
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I was not actually thinking of using `@ExchangeAware` to naively inject some (which? :) ) specific exchange, but more as a way to signal to the framework to intercept any access to that field. At that point the framework should use the exchange that it would have used had it had to bind an exchange parameter (instead of using the current exchange reference (which is probably null)).

But why not making it simpler. How about doing it this way:

```
class MyClass
{
    @ExchangeAware
    Exchange getExchange() {return null;}

    void doSomething(........)
    {
        getExchange().getIn().....

        .......
    }
}
```

The framework could override `@ExchangeAware` methods with a method that would return the current exchange.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible. Also its likely not a good idea as then the MyClass is no longer thread safe. What if 2 concurrent Exchanges is being routed and calls the same MyClass instance? Then the injected `@ExchangeAware` would be whatever the last has injected which can interfere with threading.

Its better to keep your pojo thread safe and pass in Exchange as part of the parameter - then they are thread safe.

However for `CamelContext` its a different story as there is only one instance, so your class can implement `CamelContextAware` and have the `CamelContext` injected

Comment: Thanks for referring to my question. :) Please see my update above.

Comment: I I have two camelContexts in my application, and I implement CamelContextAware (which context will be injected to my class) ??

Answer (score -1):

It's Possible with Camel 2.9.

If the method is doSomething(Exchange exchange, String someOtherParam) {}

then such a method can be invoked from route as below:

**.bean(bean_object_name, "doSomething(*, 'someOtherValue')")**

here * (wildcard) will let Camel decide and inject the exchange object.
For more details refer: http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

Comment: I explicitly wrote that I do not want to specify the exchange as a parameter.